# how to connect a usb wireless adapter with usb extension

Tags: cable, wireless-adapter

I have a 3 meter usb extension for my tl wn722n, when I connect to a computer, the device is like connect... disconnect... and keep repeating, I have also shortened it to 0.5 meters and kept repeating, before I have also tried with a pendrive and it still works even though the cable length is 3 meters, please help me!

usb type: usb 2.0
tl-wn722n v1

Answer (score 0):

This connect-reconnect cycle suggests that the cable can't provide as much power as the adapter needs. You'll need a higher quality cable.